# Echo SQL data in order of date added using Union All

Tags: php, mysql, echo, union-all

So I am working with a client to implement a similar system as the "badges and privileges system" on StackExchange. Although in her system, she is looking to use points and rewards for her staff. It's the same basic principle. The users are rewarded points for good team work and gain rewards from these points. I thought it would be handy to add the same kind of feature which SE uses to display these in the top nav bar, where it shows your rep and badges in order of the date you have earned either of them. This is my issue, I have found help retrieving the data together from the two separate tables but am not sure how I would display these results in order of date earned? As an example:

`User ID #1 has earned 50 points on 18/12/2015` would be in `ap_user_points` table

`User ID #1 has earned 'The Gift Voucher' reward on '17/12/2015'`

If I simply:

`echo $row8['reward'] . $row8['points_added']`

It would echo as:

`The Gift Voucher 50`

Where I need it in order by date as:

`50`

`The Gift Voucher`

If you look at your rep and badge icon in the nav bar you'll see what I'm getting at here, it's a similar system.

```
            <?php
$user_id = $_SESSION['userid'];                 
$sql8 = "
SELECT r.reward_id,                    
       r.user_id, 
       r.reward as reward, 
       r.date_earned as date_earned,
       r.badge_desc,

       NULL AS points_added,               
       NULL AS added_for,
       NULL AS date_added
   FROM ap_user_rewards as r 
   WHERE r.user_id = '$user_id' 

UNION ALL

SELECT NULL, 
       NULL, 
       NULL, 
       NULL,
       NULL,

       p.points_added AS points_added, 
       p.added_for AS added_for,
       p.date_added AS date_added
   FROM ap_user_points as p 
   WHERE p.user_id = '$user_id' ORDER BY date_earned DESC, date_added DESC;";

  $result8 = $conn->query($sql8);

        if ($result8->num_rows > 0) {
          // output data of each row
        while($row8 = $result8->fetch_assoc()) {


            ////// NOT SURE WHAT TO ECHO HERE? 

    }
}
?>
```

Comment: This code appears to be VULNERABLE to SQL injection. Use **prepared statements** with **bind placeholders**.  if you can't do that, at the very minimum, run the potentially unsafe value `$user_id` through a `mysqli_real_escape_string`-type function before it's included in SQL. How is it possible in 2015 that we are still writing code that is so blatantly vulnerable to SQL injection?

Comment: This is just example code to get a rough idea, this is nowhere near complete at all yet and I just needed to add an idea of how I will be retrieving my results. I hope to significantly improve any security flaws before production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another column to the result set. In that new column, populate it from both queries... looks like it would be the `date_added` expression in the first query and the `date_earned` expression in the second query.  When those are in the same column, then ordering is easy.  (This also assumes that these expressions are of the same or compatible datatypes, preferably DATE, DATETIME or TIMESTAMP.)

Then you can order by ordinal position, e.g. `ORDER BY 2` to order by the second column in the resultset.

```
SELECT a1
     , b1
     , NULL
     , NULL
     , a1 AS sortexpr 
  FROM ...
 UNION ALL
SELECT NULL
     , NULL
     , x2
     , y2
     , x2 AS sortexpr
  FROM ...
 ORDER BY 5 DESC
```

---

That's just one possibility.  If you can't add an extra column, to line up the expressions from the two queries, then you need a way to discriminate which query is returning the row. I typically include a literal as a discriminator column.

Then you can use implicit-style UNION syntax, wrapping the queries in parens...

```
( SELECT 'q1' AS `source`
       , a1
       , b1   AS date_earned
       , NULL
       , NULL AS date_added
    FROM ...
)
UNION ALL
( SELECT 'q2'  AS `source`
       , NULL
       , NULL  AS date_earned
       , x2
       , y2    AS date_added
    FROM ...
 )
 ORDER BY IF(`source`='q1',date_earned,date_added) DESC
```

---

**Followup**

I may have misunderstood the question. I though the question was how to get the rows from a UNION/UNION ALL returned in a particular order.

Personally, I would write the query to include a discriminator column, and then line up the columns as much as I could, so they would be processed the same.

As an example:

```
SELECT 'reward'        AS `source`
     , r.date_earned   AS `seq`
     , r.user_id       AS `user_id` 
     , r.date_earned   AS `date_earned`
     , r.reward_id
     , r.reward
     , r.badge_desc
     , NULL            AS `points_added`  
     , NULL            AS `added_for`
  FROM r ...

 UNION ALL

SELECT 'points'        AS `source`
     , p.date_added    AS `seq`
     , p.user_id       AS `user_id`
     , p.date_added    AS `date_earned`
     , NULL
     , NULL
     , NULL
     , p.points_added  AS `points_added`
     , p.added_for     AS `added_for`
  FROM p ...

 ORDER BY 2 DESC, 1 DESC
```

(It's probably not really necessary to return `user_id`, since we already know what the value will be. I've returned it here to demonstrate how the columns from the two resultsets can be "lined up".)

Then, when I fetched the rows...

```
  if ( $row8['source'] == 'points' )  {

      # process columns from a row of 'points' type
      echo $row8['badge_desc'];
      echo $row8['user_id'];

  } elsif ( $row8['source'] == 'reward' )  {

      # process columns from a row of 'reward' type
      echo $row8['added_for'];
      echo $row8['user_id'];

  }
```

That's how I would do it.

Comment: So with using this system, how would I `echo` my results to show them in the correct order like `point, reward, point, point, reward, point` rather than in groups like `point, point, point, reward, reward, reward` as I know if I just echo reward or echo points_added it wouldn't work?

Comment: I think I misunderstood your question. I thought you were asking how to get the resultset ordered in SQL. The approach I would use is to return the rows in the order that I want them presented, and then just present them in the order they are returned. I would "line up" the columns from the two queries. If I had special processing, handle the rows in a different way depending on which query returned it, I would use a discriminator column, Based on the value of that, I would handle rows from one source one way, and rows from the other source another way, pick out which columns are to be used.